# Any idiom for a person who has solution of every single problem

Tags: single-word-requests, idiom-requests

i am looking for a single word request or a relatable idiom for a person who has solution of every single problem.. in hindi we call them "jugadu".

I am not really looking for something like "Jack of all trades" or omniscient.. may be a more specific term.

Comment: I would use "instant expert": Put hot water on him and he becomes an expert.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jugaad

Comment: If you are looking for someone who has all the answers in a particular field of knowledge, English uses the loan word *guru*.  From Hindi.  *Computer guru* etc

Answer (score 3):

I think you may use

[Mr. Fixit](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/mr--fixit):

> - a person who epitomizes the ability or tendency to manage situations or solve problems (sometimes used with Miss, Ms., or Mrs. instead of Mr. when referring to a female).

(Dictionary.con)

[The New Partridge Dictionary of Slang and Unconventional English](https://books.google.it/books?id=mAdUqLrKw4YC&pg=PA1303&dq=%22mr%20fixit%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiOpa-ipIbdAhVHyqQKHS3EBb0Q6AEIJDAA#v=onepage&q=%22mr%20fixit%22&f=false)  gives the folowing definition and usage example of Mr Fixit:

> noun used as an informal title for someone who is able to 'fix' things, whether from a technical knowledge or political influence. (UK, 1984 'Mr' may be replaced with another title as appropriate.)
>
> - Maybe help is at hand with rugby league's Mr Fixit Maurice Lindsay, having just revealed his involvement in negotiation. (The Observer, 2003)

Comment: This is the best answer so far, seeming a good match for the definition.  @user070221, if you just add one sentence explaining why you think the positive connotations match, the critics go away.

Comment: A more modern take on this would be to call someone a [Fix-it Felix](http://disney.wikia.com/wiki/Fix-It_Felix,_Jr.) after the character in the movie _Wreck-it Ralph_.

Answer (score 2):

From what I can tell as a non-Hindi speaker, there are versions of the term that describe an innovative hack or fix (jugaad), the person performing the innovative act (jugadu), or even the act itself (a slangier use of jugaad).

So another possibility, if OP is open to an American slang term, would be to call someone a MacGyver. The word stems from a 1980s television show. The title character was a government agent who was known for his wit and ingenuity.

"[To MacGyver [something]](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/macgyver)" is popular enough as a verb that it appears in the Oxford Dictionary, defined as making or repairing something "in an improvised or inventive way, making use of whatever items are at hand." It's not uncommon to describe a person as a "real MacGyver."

Answer (score 1):

"[Know-it-all](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/know-it-all)" also comes to mind, but as others have noted, it has a distinctly negative connotation that does not seem to be shared by jugadu. I've posted another answer that I believe is a better fit.

> a person who acts as though he or she knows everything and who dismisses the opinions, comments, or suggestions of others.

(Dictionary.com)